# How to display a div only in UC mini browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, proxy

Below is a simple markup. Can anyone please help me with a script that displays a div with class "info-box" only in uc mini browser. it should be hidden in rest of the browser.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>UC Mini</title>
</head>
<style>
.info-box {
  display:none;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="info-box">My content here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Always enclose **style** tag within **head**..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

CSS:

```
.info-box {
  display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/^Mozilla\/5\.0 .+ Gecko\/$/)) {
  $(".info-box").show();
}
else {
  $(".info-box").hide();
}
```

Although this works, it is mostly not recommended. You should focus on a more universal approach.

Comment: Thank You. It works well. Is there a way we can show the same div in speed mode only?

Regards.

Comment: The two patterns, for UC Browser and UC Mini ->

# UC Browser
"Mozilla/5.0 (..) .. UCBrowser/10.7.9.856 U2/1.0.0 .."

# UC Mini with Speed Mode on (enabled by default)
"UCWEB/2.0 (..) .. UCBrowser/10.7.9.856 U2/1.0.0 Mobile"

You can modify the pattern in the answer to match according to your requirement. Please mark the answer as correct, if you feel so. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Shobhit, I have already marked the answer as correct. Now to be very frank I am  a laymen. These patterns make no sense to me. Could you plesae update the code as you had done earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CSS, for targeting browser

```
html[data-useragent*='UCBrowser'] .info-box
{
  display: block;
}
```